# Python csv module vs pandas.read_csv and Python xlrd vs pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

In python, we can use either the `csv module` or the `pandas.read_csv` function to handle csv files.  For Excel files we can use the `xlrd module` or the `pandas.read_excel` function.

I use pandas a lot and I feel that the read_csv and read_excel functions come in handy for me. 
Can anyone explain me what are the pros and cons of each of these methods?

Comment: Well, the `pandas` functions give you a `pandas` data structure, so if that is what you want then that is what you should use...

Comment: FYI check this out: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file

Comment: To my understanding the `pandas.read_excel` function actually uses `xlrd` under the hood.

Comment: Hi, all. thank you so much! All your answers are helpful!

Comment: @Xukrao Yep, `pd.read_excel` doesn't even work unless you also have xlrd installed.

Answer (score 0):

### Important note: [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) No longer supports `.xlsx` files!

This change happened in [version 2.0.0](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id1)

However regarding CSV files I think it would be interesting to do a speed comparison between `pandas` and `csv`.

My experience is that the `pandas` module reads CSV files more strictly. If a column is all numbers and one row is empty, `pandas` produces a `NaN` value unless you use `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` or something similar. This can be annoying if you have mixed data types or if you expect `None` or blank values in a column.  The `csv` library seems to handle this a little nicer.

When I used `csv` on python2, `utf-8` was a *nightmare*, but I assume that's better now with python3.